# pointer to struct - a few questions

Tags: pointers, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* Link list node */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

/* Function to reverse the linked list */
static void reverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node *prev   = NULL;
    struct node *current = *head_ref;
    struct node *next;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next  = current->next; 
        current->next = prev;  
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    *head_ref = prev;
}
```

1. What are the lines that start with struct in the reverse function responsible of?
   do they extend the original struct or creating new structs  that the original struct pointing to? I don't really understand why there is no name to the original struct
2. Is there a diffrence between  `struct node *next;` and `struct node* next;`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Line `struct node *prev` is declaration of variable `prev` of type "pointer to struct node". These lines just declare some local variables. `prev` contains a pointer to the last processed node, `current` contains a pointer to the currently processing node and `next` is used to save a pointer to the next node of original list.
2. There's no difference between `struct node *next` and `struct node* next`.

Comment: Thanks. Why do i need `int data;` inside the struct? Is that where the data is saved? If so, how? I don't see any reference to data in the code beside in the struct.

Comment: Yes, the node contains field `data` that holds the actual information and field `next` which is a pointer to the next node in the list.

Answer (score 1):

@willys is right. As we know struts is group of similar and un-similar datatype.When struct is created , it allocates a block of memory.And that memory has an address.

```
struct node{
    int age;
    char name[20];
    struct node *next_address; //Address of its type (self referential structure)
}
```

This above struct allocates a block of memory . Inside this block 3 different data is storing (age,name and a address of structure `node`)

When you want to store more blocks (for storing more data ) , you need to allocate more struct.But, there is a problem when all structs are allocated in memory , they don't have any relation between each other.Its a cause of memory leak.

So, keep the address field on each block of allocated memory, so that any block of memory can store the address of its nearest block.

Its , the real flavor value of Linked List.So, there is no confusion about the name of the struct.